# How to generate a serializable java class in Clojure by gen-class?

Tags: serialization, clojure, clojure-java-interop, gen-class

We need to serialize a bunch of Java objects generated by Clojure into a file by Java Serialization mechanism.

```
(gen-class
 :name lancelot.Instance
 :extends cc.mallet.types.Instance)

(gen-class
 :name lancelot.FilterPipe
 :extends cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe
 :prefix "-filter-"
 :methods [[pipe [cc.mallet.types.Instance] lancelot.Instance]])

(defn -filter-pipe [this ^cc.mallet.types.Instance inst]
  (.setData inst (clojure.string/join " "
    (filter normal-word? (clojure.string/split (.getData inst) #"\s+"))))
  inst)

(gen-class
 :name lancelot.SegmentorPipe
 :extends cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe
 :prefix "-segmentor-"
 :methods [[pipe [cc.mallet.types.Instance] lancelot.Instance]])

(defn -segmentor-pipe [this ^cc.mallet.types.Instance inst]
  (.setData inst (seg/seg (.getData inst)))
  inst)
```

As above, instances of lancelot.FilterPipe and lancelot.SegmentorPipe need to be serialized. We found that writing object stream is OK, but reading object stream are not work after we re-compile the code.

> Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.io.InvalidClassException:
>   lancelot.SegmentorPipe; local class incompatible: stream classdesc
>   serialVersionUID = 2583852145887230781, local class serialVersionUID =
>   -2255006751011717591  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:579)   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)

Since serialVersionUID is static and final, but it seems that gen-class can only generate instance level final field. So the problem is that I can not set a specific serialVersionUID for the generated class.

Any advice for the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. Since serialVersionUID is static and final, but it seems that gen-class can only generate instance level final field. That is the reason!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1584112/117220

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add Serializable

`(gen-class
 :name lancelot.Instance
 :implements [java.io.Serializable]
 :extends cc.mallet.types.Instance)`